# React-Native, ListView + JSON Fetch DataSource Not Updating

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to update DataSource after a call to JSON url but the ListView just not updating, The thing is when the app is loading first time, I can't see the data in the ListView, however, When I'm using the "Hot Update..." Just pressing on Ctrl+S In Visual Studio Code, The list suddenly appearing in the ListView..

What can be the issue so the list doesn't loaded on the first time? just on the second time?

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([])
    };
  }


states = {
    index: 1,
    routes: [
      { key: '1', title: 'RECOMMANDED' },
      { key: '2', title: 'MY STATIONS' }
    ]
  };

  _handleChangeTab = (index) => {
    this.setState({ index });
  };

  _renderHeader = (props) => {
    return <TabBar {...props} />;
  };

  _renderScene = ({ route }) => {


    switch (route.key) {
    case '1':
      return <View style={[ styles.page, { backgroundColor: '#fff' } ]}><ListView
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
          enableEmptySections={true}
        /></View>;
    case '2':
      return <View style={[ styles.page, { backgroundColor: '#fff' } ]}><Text>2</Text></View>;
    default:
      return null;
    }
  };

componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        var movies = responseJson.movies;
        this.setState({
          dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(responseJson.movies)
        });
      }).done();
  }



renderRow(dataRow) {
    return(
    <TouchableHighlight>
        <View>
          <Text 
            style={{fontSize: 20, color: '#000000'}} 
            numberOfLines={1}>
            { dataRow.title } - { dataRow.releaseYear }
          </Text>
          <View style={{height: 1, backgroundColor: '#dddddd'}} />
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>);
    }

  render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
        <TabViewAnimated
            style={styles.tabContainer}
            navigationState={this.states}
            renderScene={this._renderScene}
            renderHeader={this._renderHeader}
            onRequestChangeTab={this._handleChangeTab} />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

I'm using `react-native-tab-view` module.

Thanks

Comment: `this.states` should be `this.state`

Comment: I'm using `this.states` instead of `this.state` because I have already state setted for the TabNav

Comment: I saw now it's working but just after I'm just pressing "Ctrl+S" and "Hot Loading" the app.. otherwise it's showing empty, after that it's showing the list... what can be the issue?

Comment: What do you mean by I already have state setted? The state can contain many properties. Your'e component will not re-render unless you update the state. Please add your `render` method to your question.

Comment: I updated the `state` but it's still empty, just if I'm "Hot Updating" the app I can see the ListView is changed, looks like I need to re-render something as you said..

Answer (score 0):

Change your renderRow props to:

```
renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
```

You should bind this to your renderRow manually. With ES6 syntax you have no autobinding of this, so you need to do it yourself. If you don't want to handle manually this binding, you can use arrow syntax.

```
renderRow(movie) {
}
```

Have to me changed like

```
renderRow = (movie) => {
}
```

Then, like @John said you should use state.  A this.state property could have many states.

Comment: It's will not working for some reason, I changed the `renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}` and It's still not working on the first time the app is loaded, just when i'm doing "Hot Updating" I can see the list.

Comment: Could you update your question with your actual code and add the renderRow function ?